# How to get top 5 in mdx

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

How to get top 5 from mdx query?

I have a this query:

```
WITH SET [Geography].[City] AS  
   TopCount(
      [Geography].[City]
      ,5
      ,[Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost]
   ) 
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {
    CROSSJOIN(
      {
        [Date].[Calendar]
      },
      {
        [Product].[Category]
      }
    ),
    CROSSJOIN(
      {
        [Date].[Calendar].children
      },
      {
        [Product].[Category]
      }
    )
  } DIMENSION PROPERTIES children_cardinality, parent_unique_name ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {
    [Geography].[City],
    [Geography].[City].children
  } DIMENSION PROPERTIES children_cardinality, parent_unique_name ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE (
        [Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost]
      )
```

But is not working.
Now i have error
error: {"faultstring":"Query (1, 21) Parser: The syntax for '.' is incorrect.","faultcode":"XMLAnalysisError.0xc10e0002"}

The best if I not must change a code after SELECT word .

Answer (score 2):

When you create a set just declare it with no associated hierarchy so this is wrong `[Geography].[City]`.

Also there is a much more readable syntax for cross-join - just use an asterisk `*`

Try this:

```
WITH SET [CitySet] AS  
   TopCount(
      [Geography].[City]
      ,5
      ,[Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost]
   ) 
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {
       [Date].[Calendar] * [Product].[Category]
      ,[Date].[Calendar].children * [Product].[Category]
  } DIMENSION PROPERTIES children_cardinality, parent_unique_name ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {
    [CitySet],  //<<changed here [Geography].[City],
    [Geography].[City].children
  } 
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES children_cardinality, parent_unique_name ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE (
        [Measures].[Reseller Freight Cost]
      )
```